# How to clear terminal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, terminal

I am working on a program that will print out an image in the terminal with ascii letters and at the start I made a function that will clear the terminal when called but no matter where I called the function it doesn't seem to work.

I am using a Windows computer.

Any suggestions?

```
import pywhatkit
import time 
import os


def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls')


clear_screen()


from os import listdir

# get the path/directory
folder_dir = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\badapple"
for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):
    # clear the terminal
    clear_screen()
    # check if the image ends with png
    if (images.endswith(".png")):
        target_image = images
        pywhatkit.image_to_ascii_art(target_image,'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\command\\test1.txt')
        f = open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\command\\test1.txt.txt', 'r')
        file_contents = f.read()
        print (file_contents)
        f.close()
        #time.sleep(1)
        print(images)
```

I have try using only the

```
os.system('cls')
```

I try the same function in another python file and it works, but it doesn't work for this file.

Comment: Are you running the script through integrated PyCharm terminal?

Answer (score 0):

if you're running your script in an IDE, you should use

`os.system('clear')`

instead

Comment: Omg bruhhhh yess it worked thanks mate